# sqlite query error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code

```
SQLiteDatabase sb= openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/helios.maggi/Recipe.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
    Cursor c=sb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RecipeDetails", null);
    byte []myarray=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("recipeimage"));
```

The error that this code is giving is that RecipeDetails does not exist. Well the table does exist and i have checked it. What could be going wrong.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should do a getReadableDatabase() like written here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: i found the mistake. the location of the database is /data/data/<package-name>/databases/<databasename>. i have typed the wrong path in the query.